# Bold a part of string in emblem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, emblem.js, emblems

I am new to emblem and right now I am trying to bold a portion of a string in emblem but adding tag simply show them as string.

I want to bold text "Apple Safari" here and my code is:

> .class-name: .class-name2  A recent version of Apple Safari

required string should be like this:

A recent version of **Apple Safari**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it working right by adding span before plain text as well and code is

```
 .class-name: .class-name2
    %span A recent version of
    %span.bold  Google Chrome
```

Previously I was trying something like this

```
 .class-name: .class-name2
    A recent version of
    %span.bold  Google Chrome
```

and this was giving an error.